# Drupal 6 - sticky image with link

Tags: html, css, drupal

I have a Drupal 6 website and would like to place a contact button image on the right-hand middle side of the website. The idea is that when the user scrolls down the page, the button remains in its position. What's the easiest way of implementing that? If possible please provide procedures as I'm not very skilled with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If button is suppose to always stay in one place then you don't need JS at all. Just set it's position to fixed and it will always stay at one place. You need that button on every page put it's code page.tpl.php template file...